# Initializing a Struct in Swift Error: Generic parameter could not be inferred

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to declare a struct in a class without providing the parameters. The struct will need to be initialized by a function but should be visible to the entire class. Normally, I'm able to do `var myStruct : MyStruct?` but this time it's giving me an error.

`Generic parameter 'Type' could not be inferred`

Am I initializing the struct incorrectly?

How I'm using it:

```
class MyClass: {

    static let sharedInstance = MyClass()
    private override init() {}

    let myStruct = MyStruct? // <-- Above Error occurs here. 
    // let myStruct = MyStruct<Int>? // <-- Error: Expected member name or constructor call after type name
    // let myStruct = MyStruct<Int>?() // <-- Error: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'MyStruct<Double>?' with no arguments

    func runFunction(A: Int, B: Int) {
       myStruct(var1: A, var2: B) // <-- I need to initialize here.
    }
    func otherFunction() {
       myStruct.doStuff() // <-- And have access to it in other functions
    }
```

Code for my struct:

```
public struct MyStruct<Type: CustomInput>: CustomProtocol {
    public let myVar1: Type
    public let myVar2: Type
    public init(var1: Type, var2: Type) {
        self.myVar1 = var1
        self.myVar2 = var2
    }

...
}
```

Comment: `let myStruct = MyStruct?` what are you trying to do in this line? And you should tell it the generic type "Type" you are using. If it is `Int`, you should make it clear as `MyStruct<Int>` Otherwise it will complain it cant be inferred.

Comment: I'm trying to declare `myStruct` variable so that it is accessible for the entire class, but I can't initialize it immediately because I don't have access to the parameters until I call `runFunction`. I tried setting `MyStruct<Int>` but got `Expected member name or constructor call after type name`.

Comment: Ah, nevermind! I mistook `=` for `:`. It's now longer throwing the error

Comment: You either mean "let myStruct: MyStruct" or "let myStruct = MyStruct ()". What you write doesn't work.

Comment: dmr07: Please please don't use "throwing an error" in this situation. Throwing an error happens when your code performs a throw(). You mean "the compiler shows an error in my code".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a generic type, the generic parameter is actually considered to be part of the type. So the type of your struct isn't `MyStruct`, it's `MyStruct<Int>` (or whatever generic type you use. Therefore, you can't just declare the type by itself if there's not any information for the compiler to use to infer the actual type. Instead, you have to include the generic type in your declaration:

`var myStruct: MyStruct<Int>?`

Comment: Just tried it and got an error saying `Expected member name or constructor call after type name`; setting it to `var myStruct: MyStruct<Int>?.self` got rid of the error somehow. Why is this?

Comment: Are you sure you used `:` and not `=`?

Comment: @dmr07: You are grasping. Read up what the "self" means. Let Xcode show you the type of myStruct.